# How to get a text from disabled text box in selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium-ide

the Scenario is as follows: 
A text box is disabled for editing manually.To change a text value in a text box a button needs to be clicked. After clicking on a button,a window appears with a drop down list.select a value from drop down and then only text within disabled text box will change.
I need to get value from that textbox to check and then again to check a changed value.

Comment: What have you got so far? Any code that you can share?

Comment: <input id="txtCircStatus" class="txt" type="text" disabled="disabled">                                                  I got this option- storeValue ( locator, variableName ) but this isnt working for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you install the jQuery add-on (Which is just a small addition to your user-extensions.js file), you can then use jQuery to ascertain (and grab) the value of the text field.

Below is the full jQuery code you need to add (Or create in), your user-extensions.js field.

```
function jQuery (selector)
{
    return selenium.browserbot.getUserWindow().jQuery(selector);
}
```

Once you've done that, the .val() Method of getting items will work a treat such as.

```
jQuery('selector').val()
```

Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd do this is to use the disabled status as a locator

```
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>css=[disabled=disabled]</td>
    <td>text</td>
</tr>
```

If there is more than one disabled field on there you could just ad an nth modifier to find the specific field you're after, e.g.

```
    <td>css=[disabled=disabled]:nth(1)</td>
```